# Unable to install any package through pip on Ubuntu 20.04 - SSL error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip

I get the following errors whenever I try to install any package through pip3:

```
(base) user@user:~$ pip3 install pprint
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Requirement already satisfied: pprint in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.1)
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Tried to install the ssl module, but that didn't work either.

```
(base) user@user:~$ pip3 install ssl
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting ssl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/ssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/ssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/ssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/ssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/ssl/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/ssl/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/ssl/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ssl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ssl
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

There were a couple of suggestions given in some of the other posts, but they didn't solve my problem. I tried the following in the terminal:

```
pip install --upgrade --user pip --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
```

But it didn't work.

I have multiple versions of python installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. [These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJLyY.jpg) versions show up in visual studio code.
I'm scared about deleting one of the python installations, as I feel that might wreck the OS.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: A bit tangential to your question, but the statement "*I'm scared about deleting one of the python installations, as I feel that might wreck the OS.*" is a bit perplexing to me. Does Ubuntu have a critical dependency on Python being installed? I would be surprised if it did.

Comment: @esqew I was thinking of deleting all versions of python and installing them afresh.
Did a quick research to see if that was a good idea, and I saw a lot of people on overflow suggesting against it. Turns out some of the ubuntu software, relies on python3.

Comment: Did you tried `apt install libssl-dev`?